# Testing RSS feeds

Tags: testing, rss, interop

I am looking to test an RSS Feed I have created and I am looking for some good RSS Feed applications to test with.

Comment: I have a feeling people will close this as "not programming related," but I think it is related - you're asking about how to test RSS software that you've created...  Just a thought

Comment: I came in here intending to do that based on the title, but I found it was programming related.  I don't think it'll be closed for that, though I wouldn't be surprised if it were a duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't just try a bunch and see if it works -validate it.  Let me google those for you:

- [W3C RSS validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/)
- [Experimental Online RSS 1.0 Validator](http://www.ldodds.com/rss_validator/1.0/validator.html)

Comment: Do both. The feed might be valid, but be otherwise broken - it could display weirdly, not properly set GUID's and constantly mark all articles as "new" etc..

Answer (score 2):

Firefox should work well enough for basic testing. You could also try using Google reader.

Comment: Google Reader has been discontinued.

Answer (score 2):

It would be worth testing the feed in [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/).

Also, if you're using Mac OS X, here are some good applications to test it in:

- [NetNewsWire](http://www.newsgator.com/INDIVIDUALS/NETNEWSWIRE/)
- [Apple Mail](http://www.apple.com/macosx/features/mail.html) (comes with OS X)
- [NewsFire](http://www.newsfirex.com/)
- [Times](http://acrylicapps.com/times/)

However, if it is a valid feed, you should be OK.

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Circa 2009, one great answer was the python library and website at [http://www.feedvalidator.org/](https://web.archive.org/web/20090305222337/http://feedvalidator.org//). It was supposed to be very picky and have lots of tests.

The code still exists at https://github.com/rubys/feedvalidator but hasn’t gotten much attention since [circa 2008](https://github.com/rubys/feedvalidator/graphs/contributors). It could be a good starting point for a newly-updated library. All the tests could make that easier;
[there’s a `py3` branch](https://github.com/rubys/feedvalidator/tree/py3) with a bit of progress on it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget Outlook.  Large market share and its own quirks.

Answer (score 0):

[Feed Demon](http://www.newsgator.com/Individuals/FeedDemon/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

RSS Reader applications - 
[Greatnews](http://www.curiostudio.com/)

Online RSS reader - [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/)

Also, some useful FF add-ons for such:

[Simple RSS reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5459)

[RSS Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2294)

[Sage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=rss)

[Beatnik](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4979)

Answer (score -1):

[Google Reader](http://reader.google.com)

Comment: Google Reader has been discontinued.